# How to ensure wcf service client finishs his works in silverlight?

Tags: silverlight, asynchronous, call, wait

I use wcf service client to submit changes of data for a silverlight project. The correlative codes like this:

```
    public class DispatcherCollection : UpdatableCollection<DocumentDispatcher>
{
    public override void SubmitChanges()
    {
        DocumentServiceClient client = new DocumentServiceClient();
        client.NewDocumentCompleted += (s, e) =>
        {
            // (s as DocumentServiceClient).CloseAsync();
            // do something
        };
        client.UpdateColumnCompleted += (s, e) =>
        {
            // (s as DocumentServiceClient).CloseAsync();
            // do something
        };
        client.RemoveDocumentCompleted += (s, e) =>
        {
            // (s as DocumentServiceClient).CloseAsync();
            // do something
        };
        foreach (DocumentDispatcher d in this)
        {
            if (d.IsNew)
            {
                // d=>object[] data
                client.NewDocumentAsync(data);
                d.IsNew=false;
            }
            else
            {
                foreach (string propertyName in d.modifiedProperties)
                {
                    client.UpdateColumnAsync(d.ID, GetPropertyValue(propertyName));
                }
                dd.ClearModifications();
            }
        }
        foreach (DocumentDispatcher dd in removedItems)
        {
            client.RemoveDocumentAsync(dd.ID);
        }
        removedItems.Clear();
    }
}
```

Class UpdatableCollection derives from ObserableCollection, and I implemtent logics in class DocumentDispatcher and UpdatableCollection to buffer the changes of data such as new created, property modified and removed. I use SubmitChanges method to submit all changes to server.

Now I am stuck:
1. I am at a loss when to close the client after a bunlde fo async calls. I don't know which callback is the last one.
2. What will happen when a user closes the IE immediately right after clicking the save button (it seems to be done because it runs async but in fact the updating threads are industriously running.)?

Answer (score 0):

1. You can keep a counter or use an isbusy function to monitor the callbacks from your Async calls - to make sure they all finished.
2. If the user fires off a request to the WCF service, the WCF service will complete but there will be no call back - as the application will be closed.

Answer (score 0):

I think that there is no wait handle for silverlight asynchornized call brings inconvenience. Here is my experence. I want to check and submit modifications of data which are not expicitly submitted when browser is closing. I have implemented codes in App_Exit like this:

```
 private void Application_Exit(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Document doc = EDPViewModel.CurrentViewModel.Document;
        if (doc != null) new ServiceClient().SubmitChangesAsync(doc);
    }
```

provided that in the SubmitChangesAsync method, not submitted modifications of doc are found out and submitted. Therefore, because of the asynchronized running features, while the service invoking is being sent, the application is yet immediately closed. And that will dispose related resouces of the application, including Service Invoking Tasks. So the codes above work not. I hope so eagerly that somewhere exists a mechanism, which can export a wait handle from silverlight asynchronized call, so that I can update the above codes whith this:

```
private void Application_Exit(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Document doc = EDPViewModel.CurrentViewModel.Document;
        if (doc != null)
        {
            Task t = new TaskFactory().StartNew(() => new ServiceClient().SubmitChangesAsync(doc));
            t.Wait(); 
        }
    }
```

With wait operation I can really be sure that all modifications are really definitely  submitted. So is there any similar pattern that can be used in silverlight?

Answer (score -1):

It's for me a good news, as you put it, that calls could work like the mode "requesting and forgetting". So I needn' to worry too much about data losing during submitting.

To ensure all service calls are sent out before application is closed, I think, counter is a simple and effient idea. I will try to implement it in my project.

Thank you for your help!